# jquery class change to div not working on asp,net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I have some Jquery script running on my asp.net web page which is driving me crazy.

I have a page which, when a button is pressed, first it puts a grey 'cover' over the whole screen to let the user know something is happening.

Then it runs some vb code which saves the data of the screen to the database.
Finally when completed, I want the 'cover' div to hide again...

CSS....

```
  .coverNONE{ position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); z-index:1000; width:100%; height:100%; display:none; } 
  .coverYES{ position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); z-index:1000; width:100%; height:100%; display:block; }
```

HTML/ASP.NET (part)

```
    <asp:Button id="BtnDetailsUpdate" Text="Update Record" ToolTip="This is an example-button" runat="server" onclick="BtnDetailsUpdate_Click" onclientclick="ShowCover('coverYES');"/>
... more code...

    <div id="div_Cover" runat="server" class="coverNONE"> 
    </div>
```

here is the jquery script...
ShowCover works, but HideCover doesn't (script runs, just it doesn't change the div class to 'none' (which hides it again)

```
             function ShowCover(strCode) {                     
                 $("#div_Cover").addClass('coverYES');
             }

             function HideCover(strCode) {                     
                 $("#div_Cover").addClass('coverNONE');
             }
```

vb code...

```
Protected Sub BtnDetailsUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ...code here that saves the record to database
' this code runs the script from within vb...
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, [GetType](), "none", "<script>HideCover();</script>", False)


End Sub
```

The jquery script runs from VB (I put an alert on the script and it works) but for some reason the div is not hidden (div class is not changed to coverNONE)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong....???

Comment: One of the quickest ways to troubleshoot such an issue is to look under the hood ... see what html your web server generates out of your ASP.NET code. That -- the HTML -- is what CSS and JS act on **.**

Comment: I looked under the hood as you said, but Rick's answer just below is what was required....thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function HideCover(strCode) {    
      $("#div_Cover").removeClass('coverYES');
      $("#div_Cover").addClass('coverNONE');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$("#div_Cover").removeClass('coverYES');
```

this will remove your class you added and then add class again